# How to extract a specific sentences from html text With php

Tags: php

if i have a big Large html text and i need to extract a specific sentences from it like "/user/abdullaheidtv/videos?sort=dd&view=0&page=1"

Perhaps what I need is
"/user/abdullaheidtv/videos?sort=dd&view=0&page=***12***"
or
"/user/abdullaheidtv/videos?sort=dd&view=0&page=***50***"
or
"/user/abdullaheidtv/videos?sort=dd&view=0&page=***90***"

i want to extract Anything Contains "/user/abdullaheidtv/videos?sort=dd&view=0&page=***$no***"

And only the last number is the variable

Waiting for help :)

Comment: preg_match() - it's in the manual.

Answer (score 0):

Regex can help you there.  Use `preg_match`.

```
@/user/abdullaheidtv/videos\?sort=dd\&view=\d+\&page=\d+@
```

should match.

Note, I'm using `@...@` for the regular expression so that I don't need to escape `/` every time.

HTH.

Comment: Does not work I think that the reason is No spaces before and after the string

Comment: @MohamedAdelElareef can you post some sample sentences?